# Using basicHttpbinding and get the response in raw data

Tags: wcf, soap, basichttpbinding, raw-data

I've looked all day and I couldn't able to find a correct answer on how get the response of my Web Service using basicHttpBinding without the SOAP formatting.

Can anyone know how to do that ? or another way for getting the raw data ? (like a string)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [webhttpBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.webhttpbinding(v=vs.110).aspx). Look at the following articles, it might help you:

- [Creating WCF Service with SOAP/REST Endpoints](http://dotnetspeak.com/2012/01/creating-wcf-service-with-soaprest-endpoints)
- [How to enable REST and SOAP both on the same WCF Service](http://debugmode.net/2011/12/22/how-to-enable-rest-and-soap-both-on-the-same-wcf-service/)
- [An Introduction To RESTful Services With WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd315413.aspx)